# Why is this subquery not working in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a subquery that is not working in Snowflake. I am receiving this error:

```
SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated
```

When I run the subquery in this query it does not work. However, I need to include this subquery in order to take into account the "status" column that will be used in the case statement.

Is someone able to help with this?

```
create table TBL_A (
    number_id int, country varchar(50), status varchar(50), datetime date
);
insert into TBL_A values 
(121144, 'USA', 'CLAIMED', '2021-10-10'),
(121144, 'USA', 'BOUGHT', '2021-10-11'),
(121144, 'USA', 'RETURNED', '2021-10-12'),
(121144, 'AU', 'CLAIMED', '2021-09-10'),
(121144, 'AU', 'BOUGHT', '2021-09-11');

create table TBL_B  (
    number_id int, country varchar, status varchar, 
    claimed_date date, bought_date date, returned_date date
);
```

Query I need to run:

```
insert into TBL_B (number_id, country, status, claimed_date, bought_date, returned_date)
select
    w.number_id, w.country, w.status
    , case w.status when 'CLAIMED' then w.datetime else '2999-12-31' end claimed_date
    , case w.status when 'BOUGHT' then w.datetime else '2999-12-31' end bought_date
    , case w.status when 'RETURNED' then w.datetime else '2999-12-31' end returned_date
from
(
    select x.*, (select z.status from TBL_A z where z.number_id=x.number_id and z.country=x.country and z.datetime=x.datetime) status
    from
    (
        select a.number_id, a.country, max(datetime) as datetime
        from TBL_A a
        group by a.number_id, a.country
    ) x
```

Comment: I don't think Snowflake supports correlated sub-queries in a select like that.

Comment: It appears the this can be rewritten with a straightforward join

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761235/updating-several-columns-in-one-table-from-another-table-with-a-single-column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query could be rewritten using lateral:

```
select x.*, z.status
from (select a.number_id, a.country, max(datetime) as datetime
     from TBL_A a
     group by a.number_id, a.country
) x
left join lateral(select z.status 
                 from TBL_A z 
                 where z.number_id=x.number_id 
                   and z.country=x.country 
                   and z.datetime=x.datetime) z;
```

[image]

---

The more important part is "what" the query is supposed to do. If the goal is to get latest status then `QUALIFY` is the most straighforward way to achieve it:

```
-- insert into
select  number_id, country, datetime, status
from TBL_A
qualify  rank() over (partition by number_id, country order by datetime desc) = 1;
```

[image]

---

If the goal is to get latest status plus dates of each status then conditional aggregation is the way to go:

```
select a.number_id, a.country,
   (array_agg(status) within group(order by datetime desc)[0])::varchar as latest_status,
   coalesce(max(case when status = 'CLAIMED'  THEN datetime END),'2999-12-31'::date) as claimed_date,
   coalesce(max(case when status = 'BOUGHT'   THEN datetime END),'2999-12-31'::date) as bought_date,
   coalesce(max(case when status = 'RETURNED' THEN datetime END),'2999-12-31'::date) as returned_date
from TBL_A a
group by a.number_id, a.country;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi There! Thank you, this helps! But when there is no claimed or bought status, how would I take in account this? If there is only one status, then it should also be flagged as order

Comment: @lalaland In case of missing value the COALESCE handles it. Here by setting the value to 2999-12-31. If it should be a different one it could be adjusted: `COALESCE(max(case when status = 'CLAIMED'  THEN datetime END),max(case when status = 'BOUGHT'   THEN datetime END),'2999-12-31'::date)`

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!